# Generate RGB colors as different as possible

Tags: python, colors, rgb

I have been using the random function to generate color values xi = [a, b, c] where a, b, and c can be any number from 0 to 255.

I need ideas to write a function that generate x values as different as possible for the human eye. One of the problems I am having is that I don't know the number of x elements that will be generated. So my previous functions attempts are generating values that end up quickly converging as more and more values are generated.

Ideas?

Comment: How many different colors do you need at the most? If that number is not too high, you should manually select N human-distuingishable colors and then select colors from that list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a different colour model can help here - for example, you could use HSV, and then cycle through the hue while maintaining a consistent saturation and value.

HSV also makes it easier to generate colours which complement each other, for example, you could take 2 colours with hues 120 or 180 degrees apart.

See also

- [convert RGB values to equivalent HSV values using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612361/convert-rgb-values-to-equivalent-hsv-values-using-python)
- [hex <-> RGB <-> HSV Color space conversion with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597610/hex-rgb-hsv-color-space-conversion-with-python)